# Computing nonabelian derived functors on fibrant-cofibrant objects

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

I am learning the process of "Animation" from Cesnavicius and Scholze's paper [Purity for flat cohomology](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/flat-purity.pdf). In my understanding the animation of a category/functor is simply the nonabelian derived category/functor, but I encounterd a problem of actually computing them. Let me use $\operatorname{Ring}$, the category of commutative rings, as an example.

There is a simplicial model structure on $\operatorname{sRing}$ (the category of simplicial rings), where fibrations and weak equivalences are checked on the underlying map of simplicial sets. There is a natural functor $\operatorname{N}(\operatorname{sRing}^\circ)\rightarrow\operatorname{Ani}(\operatorname{Ring})$ which is an equivalence.

Now let $F\colon\operatorname{Ring}\rightarrow\operatorname{Ring}$ be a functor, the derived functor (or animation) of $F$ is defined using the universal property of $\operatorname{Ani}(\operatorname{Ring})$, namely $\operatorname{Ani}(F)\colon\operatorname{Ani}(\operatorname{Ring})\rightarrow\operatorname{Ani}(\operatorname{Ring})$ preserves sifted colimits and restricts to $F$ on $\operatorname{Ring}^{\operatorname{sfp}}$ (namely those rings which are retracts of a finite polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$)

Now my question is: does $\operatorname{Ani}(F)$ coincides with $F$ on $\operatorname{N}(\operatorname{sRing}^\circ)$? More precisely, we can construct a functor $\operatorname{N}(\operatorname{sRing}^\circ)\stackrel{F}{\rightarrow}\operatorname{N}(\operatorname{sRing})\rightarrow\operatorname{Ani}(\operatorname{Ring})$, does this functor preserve sifted colimits?